# Onload iframe in Javascript wont work

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden"      onload="img.src='http://sjabbo.net/logo.png?'+(+new Date())">
<img id="img"
   onload="iframe.src='http://sjabbo.net'"
   onerror="iframe.src='offline.html'"
width="0px" height="0px">

<iframe width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
</body>
```

So, if the local user has an internet connection, then the iframe should change to "http://sjabbo.net" but if not, then "offline.html"
but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Why you don't call a function on the onload and then in that function assign the img?

Comment: Could you please post a code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<img id="img" src="http://sjabbo.net/logo.png"
   onload="document.getElementById('iframe').src='http://sjabbo.net'"/>

<iframe src="offline.html" id="iframe" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
</body>
```

You could introduce "testing" page like this:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<img id="img" src="http://sjabbo.net/logo.png"
   onload="document.getElementById('iframe').src='http://sjabbo.net'"
   onerror="document.getElementById('iframe').src='offline.html'"/>

<iframe src="testing.html" id="iframe" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't just use "img", because, to JavaScript, it's not defined anywhere globally. If you want to access the image by its ID, you need to do the following. Also, I'm guessing you want to have a timestamp instead of the long date. Put something like this in your `onload`:

```
document.getElementById('img').src = 'http://sjabbo.net/logo.png?' + (new Date()).getTime()
```

Do the same with your iframe (you'll have to assign it an ID first).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've understood how web works.

You don't need to add an onload to every element that has a child. Each element is created one after another. So for now remove all your onloads.

You seem to want to wait to know if your image gets loaded correctly or not. Depending on this you want to activate your iframe.

You'll want to create a javascript tag ( or for good practice, create a js file ).

```
var img = document.getElementById('img'),
    iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'); //add iframe as an id to your iframe
img.onload = function(){
  //this is called when the image is finished loading.
  iframe.src = 'http://sjabbo.net';
};
img.onerror = function(){
  //this is called when the image wasn't able to load properly
  iframe.src = 'offline.html'; //To be honest this doesn't make much sense
  //You should instead just hide the iframe and the image
  iframe.style.visibility = 'none';
  img.style.visibility = 'none';
};
img.src = 'http://sjabbo.net/logo.png?' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

For future programming please try to seperate your js and css from your html. It is not good practice what you are currently doing.